# Cannot select a dropdown item in jQuery to make it display a hidden textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, forms

I am trying to get a paragraph with some text and a textbox to show up when a certain option in the dropdown select menu on my form is clicked. Similar code worked for radio buttons, but doesn't seem to in this case. I would really appreciate any help that I can get on this. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hN63N/)

HTML:

```
<select name="select1">
<option value="doctor" id="doctor1">Doctor</option>
<option value="nurse" id="nurse1">Nurse</option>
<option value="other" id="other1">Other</option>
</select>
<div class="otherprof">
<p>Please list your profession:
<input type="text" name="otherproftext" id="otherproftext" maxlength="20">
</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".otherprof").hide();
$("#other1").click(function () {
    $(".otherprof").show();
});
$("#doctor1").click(function () {
    $(".otherprof").hide();
});
$("#nurse1").click(function () {
    $(".otherprof").hide();
});
});
```

Idea is that the textbox stays hidden until users click on  "Other" in the dropdown, which in turn is supposed to display the textbox immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the onchange event on the select, not click on the options.

```
$("[name='select1']").on("change", function(){     //listen for change event on the select
    $(".otherprof").toggle(this.value==="other");  //toggle show/hide based on selected value
}).change();  //trigger the change event so default value is checked
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MPS53/)

Comment: You beat me to the answer, but here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hN63N/1/) on JSFiddle. :)

Comment: Works nicely, thanks. I wonder why jQuery won't let you use .click in this case. Anyway, I will accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: @user3361043 it is not jQuery, there is no click event for options in most browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Add the style attribute to the div `otherprof` and it will be hidden initially

```
<select name="select1">
  <option value="doctor" id="doctor1">Doctor</option>
  <option value="nurse" id="nurse1">Nurse</option>
  <option value="other" id="other1">Other</option>
</select>
<div class="otherprof" style="display:none;">
 <p>Please list your profession:
  <input type="text" name="otherproftext" id="otherproftext" maxlength="20">
 </p>
</div>
```